# Quick way to migrate DirectShow filters to Media Foundation MFTs

Tags: directshow, ms-media-foundation

I have some custom DirectShow filters (for Encoding / Deconding / Mux / Demux).

and I want to use them on Media Foundation as MFTs.

I have heard some people say:

"Microsoft claims all DirectShow filters only have to add a few code to migrate to MFTs"

acturally, I doubt there is a quick way. because the methods, APIs between DShow and MediaFoundation are different.

But since somebody tell me this information, I would like to ask :

"Is this true? and how could I do the quick migration?"

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think they are referring to DMOs. For a native dshow filter, you would need a wrapper that is not dissimilar to the filter that is used as a proxy for DMOs.

Comment: I have asked the guy who told this, and turns out he took the information wrong. So, this is a false alarm.

Answer (score 0):

There's no quick migration. You have to create something that can return the IMFTransform* from an IBaseFilter*.

I 'm doing that in an application I 'm currently working on.